# MySQL: Query to get the data with constraints

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

Hi im working on a project, where i have a table named users it has data like name,email,dateofBirth(yyyy-mm-dd) where user_id is PRI Key

I need a query where i should get all the mail id's of the users, except the one who is celebrating the birthday tomorrow

example : If a,b,c,d are users if d is celebrating birthday tomorrow i need a query for getting others mail id's except d's the before day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
WHERE dateofBirth != CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 day
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm also getting the email of one who is celebrating their birthday tomorrow, i don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
SELECT "email" 
  FROM "users" 
 WHERE "dateofBirth" <> ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT email 
 FROM `users` 
 WHERE `dateofBirth` <> DATE(NOW()+ INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this you will required reult

```
  select email from users where dateofbirth <> DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this way.

```
 SELECT email
 FROM users 
 WHERE dateofBirth = ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Try this.